# "Validation failed: Email is invalid" Hartl Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've broken something.  After section 9.3.2 of Hartl's Rails Tutorial, I suddenly get 27 errors all saying something similar to:

```
23) Authentication signin with valid information 
 Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email is invalid
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've looked for typos or misplaced '', which have been my previous downfalls, but haven't seen any.  Here are some relevant pages.

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end 
end
```

lib/tasks/sample_data.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
  User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                 password: "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar")
    99.times do |n|
      name = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
               email: email,
               password: password,
               password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User Pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before(:each) do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }
    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'All users') }

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user)}

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "after submission it should" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign Up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before { valid_signup } 

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_welcome_message('Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Save changes" }

      it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }

      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
  end
end
```

authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
    end

      describe "after visiting another page" do

        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_error_message('Invalid') }
      end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign In') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
          before do
            visit edit_user_path(user)
            fill_in "Email",     with: user.email
            fill_in "Password",  with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
          end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What are validations in model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've wrongly defined `:email` in the factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end 
end
```

Should be

```
sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had deviated from Hartl's path slightly (changing from email addresses with domain @railstutorials.org) and got caught up in resetting the database (since I had created emails then told the factory to create duplicate emails), so thought I may have broke it there somehow.